# Enable or disable maintenance mode store view 2

Tags: magento2, store-view, maintenance

Is there any option to enable maintenance mode for a specific store view.

Comment: Magento does NOT have this feature. So, you have to do customization

Answer (score 1):

Not provided by Magento2 itself

You'd customize or try some 3rd party module, some examples

https://www.hiddentechies.com/coming-soon-store-maintenance-magento-2.html

https://marketplace.magento.com/dotsquares-maintenance.html

This one is free https://github.com/creatuity/magento2-custom-maintenance (not sure if this works per store view, the others above seem to do it)